# Unable to get delivery notification using Wire2air API

Tags: sms

I am using wire2air api for sending bulk sms and polling. but unable to get the delivery status for SMS.
I also have a look out their documentation here http://www.wire2air.com/developer_apis.asp
but unable to find any help from it.

also for replypath parameter in APi it is mentioned that "ONLY available in advance developer API."

So also not able to know what advance developer APi. is do i need to purchase different plan for it.

Any help on this is Appreciated.

Comment: You can contact on this no 1-(800)-209-2188

Comment: anyone can help on How to fetch Sent/Received reports from Wire2Air API and show into a website

Answer (score 0):

Amit,

In order to get real-time delivery status from wire2air, you would need to implement their real-time delivery reports webservice. You should contact wire2air support, to activate the feature. If you're using a shared short code, Replypath is only used for receiving replies back to your server, this allow end users to reply to text message without using keyword.

--Sam